# Error when updating npm : missing node-gyp module

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, npm

I am trying to install nodejs on my machine (ubuntu 14.04).

What I did so far, without error :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Checking the versions :

```
user@home:~$ node -v
v8.10.0
user@home:~$ npm -v
5.7.1
```

Now I want to upgrade `npm`, here comes the error :

```
user@home:~$ npm install -g npm@latest
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'

user@home:~$ sudo npm install -g npm
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'
```

I tried installing it :

```
user@home:~$ sudo apt-get install node-gyp
```

But I get the same error when I try to update npm.

What can I do to get `npm` to work ?